# Two Variable Limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{6(1-\cos(xy))}{x^2y\sin(2y)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I don't really know how to continue this question, this is my work so far:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{6(1-\cos(xy))}{x^2y\sin(2y)}$$

$$= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{6(1-\cos(xy))}{x^2y\sin(2y)} \cdot \frac{1+\cos(xy)}{1+\cos(xy)}$$

$$= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \cdot \frac{6 \sin(xy)}{x \sin(2x)}$$

$$= 3 \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{\cos(y) \sin(y) x} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos(xy)}$$

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{6(1-\cos(xy))}{x^2y\sin(2y)}&=6\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{(xy)^2\frac{\sin(2y)}y}\\&=3\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{(xy)^2}\times\frac{2y}{\sin(2y)}\\&=\frac32,\end{align}since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac12\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{y\to0}\frac y{\sin y}=1.$$